# Trajectory of a projectile meets a moving object (2D)

Tags: math, 2d

I've looked for quite some time now to find a nice math solution for my cannon firing a projectile at a moving target, taking into account the gravity. I've found a solution for determining the angle at which the cannon should be fired, based on the cannon's position, the target's position and the start velocity. The formula is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile#Angle_.CE.B8_required_to_hit_coordinate_.28x.2Cy.29.

[image]

This works perfectly. However, my target is moving, so if I shoot at the target and the projectile takes a few seconds to get to its destination, the target is long gone. The target's x position can be determined from the time. Lets say that: **x = 1000 - (10 * t)** where t is the time in seconds. The y can be described as: **y = t**.

The problem is, that t depends on the angle at which the cannon is fired.

Therefor my question is: How can I modify the formula as described in the wiki, so that it takes the moving target into account?

Additionally, I might have been looking at the wrong words here or on Google, but I didn't find any solution describing this exact problem.

Thank you in advance for your braintime!

As a reply to your comments. I want to fire it now and the target is in range given the speed. I think that are all constraints that are applicable to this problem.

As a reply to the answer, lets take a look at this example:

The cannon is at {0, 0} and isn't moving.
The start speed is 100 m/s.
The target is at {1000, 0} and is moving with 10 m/s towards the cannon (v = -10 m/s).

What angle should I use to hit the moving target, when I want to fire at t=0 (immediately)?

If I shoot without taking the target's speed into account, I would aim at {1000, 0} and the angle could be calculated using the mentioned formula. But it will miserably miss the target because its moving.

As Beta suggested, I could aim at i.e. {500, 0}, calculate what time it takes for the  projectile to arrive at those coords (lets say 5 seconds) and wait until the target is 5 seconds away from {500, 0}, being {550, 0}. But this means that I have to wait 450m or 45 seconds before I can fire my cannon. And I don't want to wait, because the target is killing me in the mean time.

I really hope this gives you enough info to go with. I'd prefer some math solution, but anything that would get me really close to firing "right away" and "right on target" is also much appreciated.

Comment: "The problem is, that t depends on the angle at which the cannon is fired". This sounds strange.

Comment: The problem is underconstrained. When do you want to fire? As soon as possible? When the target is closest? So as to hit when the target is closest? So as to hit the target as hard as possible? So as to make the code as simple as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect finding a formula will be quite difficult. However the error in the iterative scheme below will go down by roughly a factor of v/V (v the target speed, V the projectile speed) each step.

start by taking the time of flight to be zero

Repeat

calculate the distance to the target (using time of flight)

calculate the time of flight from the distance.

Until two successive times of flight are close enough

Comment: Dear dmuir, thanks for your reply. O have to admit I don't quite follow your iterative scheme. Could you please clarify it a bit? Thanks alot!

Comment: If x(t),y(t) are the coordinates of the target at time, t, then given t we can compute the time of flight of the projectile to the target position at t, say tof(t) -- there's a formula on the wiki page you linked to. We want to solve t=tof(t) for t. I'm suggesting is that you first compute t_1 = tof(0), then t_2 = tof(t_1), then t_3 = tof(t_2) and so on, until two successive t_i's are close enough. As long as the projectile speed is bigger than the target speed, these t_i's will get closer and closer together, though you do have to watch out for the case where the target moves out of range.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is underconstrained, which means that you will have some choices. You can track the target through the air for a while, and the choice of when to fire is up to you.

If you know the target's trajectory, and you know how to hit a stationary target, then you can choose *where* you want the impact to occur. Just pick a point on the trajectory (comfortably far ahead of the target) and aim there. Then all you have to do is decide when to fire. It is easy to calculate how long the cannonball will take to reach the point of impact; it is easy to calculate where the target will be, that much time before it reaches the point of impact; when the target is *there*, pull the trigger.

Comment: Dear Beta, although I see what your getting at, taking a "rough" time buffer before firing the projectile isn't what I'm looking for. Your last sentence describes the exact problem. Both time and position of the target can be easily calculated. I want to combine them both in a single equation helping me to figure out the eventual angle determining the projectile's trajectory, which I'm pretty sure is somehow possible.

Comment: @sdk: *The problem is underconstrained.* Just fire straight up, that will work in all but a tiny subset of possible situations. There are many other approaches you could choose, but there's no point in trying to work out solutions until you decide what you want.